# intellij idea connecting to mySql

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

thanks in advance
I have a cpanel host and I have created a MySQL database on it.
I was trying to connect to MySQL via IntelliJ Idea... for using it in Spring boot and etc but all the time I try I get connection fail error:

```
Connection to taxirkar_nettodb@109.169.71.144 failed.
[08S01] Communications link failure.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I'm getting my host IP from my cpanel host by going to "server information" and grabbing the shared IP

I have created a DB in Cpanel with name of : "nettodb".

I have assigned a user with name of "tara" to it.

the host is : "taxirkaran.com".

And my host username is : "taxirkar".

what else should i do? what I'm doing wrong?

there is the picture of my settings in intelli :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJO-cRb139jq71K48aWnYpZQY4mdtl_2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the database accept connections from a remote host?

Comment: actually I have added %.%.%.% to my cpanel host remote database(MySQL) accounts and even my pc IP ... should i do anything else?

Comment: It is possible that the server itself doesn't allow any remote connections on 3306 port, not just MySQL. You would need to consult your hosting company about that.

Comment: thanks... so i would ask them... but anyway i even made a raspberry pi Linux server myself and tried to connecting to it.. every thing is okay as i can connect to it remotely with e.g. VNC viewer but again for MySQL and intelij i get the same error... how can i make sure my port 3306 is open?

Comment: IIRC, the my.cnf file should contain the bind address config. It's by default set to 127.0.0.1, which means that only connections from localhost are accepted. It's a wild guess, of course, but I would assume this is a possibility and you normally don't have access to my.cnf on a shared host.

Comment: thank you sir... I think you're right ... I will test what you have said tonight on my raspberry server... I will tell the result, thanks